# Do systemd unit files have to be reloaded when modified?

Tags: systemd

Let's say I write a `mine.service` file. Then I use `systemctl enable mine.service`.

If I later decide to edit `mine.service`, do I have to tell `systemd` that `mine.service` was changed? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

After you make changes to your unit file, you should run `systemctl daemon-reload`, as outlined [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#daemon-reload).

> **daemon-reload**
>   Reload systemd manager configuration. This will rerun all generators (see [systemd.generator(7)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html)), reload all unit files, and recreate the entire dependency tree. While the daemon is being reloaded, all sockets systemd listens on behalf of user configuration will stay accessible.

You can then restart (or reload) your service as you desire with

```
systemctl restart your-service-name
```

(daemon-reload won't reload/restart the services themselves, just makes systemd aware of the new configuration)

Comment: I found I also needed to run a `systemctl restart` to actually restart the service itself...

Comment: Just in case, `daemon-reload` isn't universal, have got to run `systemctl --user daemon-reload` for user services.

Comment: As a note it also "delete the previous configuration created by generators" before rerunning them: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html

Comment: Bit of a syntax complaint but should != must.  And must it is, which feels lame because systemctl is smart enough to tell you that you need to reload it, but won't reload itself.

Comment: Yeah, you’re absolutely right, it does need to be run after changing a unit.

Answer (score 39):

As an addition to the answer above: In case you changed something in the `[Install]` directive, you may need to run `sudo systemctl reenable YOURUNITFILE` in order to recreate the symlinks in the .target directories.

Comment: This did the trick for me! Didn't get it why systemctl wasn't reloading the service file.