# Can I safely restart systemd on a live server?

Tags: systemd

I'm installing a package from Digital Ocean that will monitor the server, and I'm told to run `systemctl daemon-reload` on a live server. On this server there is a running web server for a production site. Can I safely do this? I understand this restarts systemd on the machine.

I think I was told to do this on another server as well, and might need to do it on more. This is the message:
`Warning: do-agent.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.`

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/a/700956/37681

Comment: @HBruijn If you post the solution as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Please upvote the answer(s) I linked to instead and I'll flag your question as a duplicate. But glad to have been of service :)