# logrotate postrotate seems not being executed

Tags: ubuntu, docker, sudo, logrotate

I have this configuration on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
/home/impulse/nginx/log/*/notice.log /home/impulse/nginx/log/*/access.status_ok.log /home/impulse/nginx/log/*/access.status_erro.log {
  daily
  nomail
  dateext
  rotate 31
  dateyesterday
  create root root
  notifempty
  nocompress
  extension .log
  # Script to notify nginx that logfile changed.
  postrotate
    docker exec -ti impulse_web sudo pkill -HUP nginx
  endscript
}
```

`docker` binary is only allowed via `sudo` on the server. The `postrotate` script is not being executed.

My question is, under which account does `logrotate` run ? And, can I log its execution to track why this isn't being applied ?

The script works when called on the terminal with `sudo`.

My current log dir:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3073955 fev  3 11:02 access.status_ok-20210128.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 jan 29 00:00 access.status_ok.log
```

Since `access.status_ok.log` is empty, the logrotate fails. And nginx keeps logging in the old file because the `postrotate` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had 2 misunderstandings:

- `HUP` signal sent to nginx makes it re-opens log files: it doesn't, `USR1` does, see here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
- The signal was sent to all nginx processes: it shouldn't, it should only be sent to the master process, see here: https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2011-January/024438.html

And one main FACEPALM reason:

- `docker exec` in the `postrotate` script must not had the `-ti` options, because it's not running in an interactive terminal.....

The debug logs from `systemd` were there all the time, but they were NOT recorded in `/var/log/syslog`. The following helped:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225401/how-to-see-full-log-from-systemctl-status-service

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083537/how-do-i-properly-install-a-systemd-timer-and-service

[Do systemd unit files have to be reloaded when modified?](https://serverfault.com/questions/700862/do-systemd-unit-files-have-to-be-reloaded-when-modified)